# заполнение Combobox значениями из столбца БД mssql WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно заполнить combobox "Art" значениями из бд (таблица "adgezia") из столбца "art". После запуска кода combobox пустой... Помогите пожалуйста исправить.
Добавил Art.ItemsSource.

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="Art" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" IsEnabled="True"/>
```

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
            cnn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source (подключение к бд)";

            string query = "SELECT art FROM adgezia";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
            DataTable table_p = new DataTable();

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(table_p);

            Art.DisplayMemberPath = "art";
            Art.ItemsSource = table_p.AsDataView();
            Art.SelectedIndex = -1;

        }
```

Comment: У вас синтакстческие ошибки в коде. А так, вы забыли присвоить `Art.ItemsSource`. То есть он пустой, потому что вы в него никаких данных не загрузили. И не пишите никогда свой код в конструкторе окна, используйте вместо этого обработчик события `Window.Loaded`, в конструкторе у вас окно еще окончательно не загрузилось, а вы в него уже грузите данные.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие ошибки в коде нужно исправить. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы спрашиваете, что нужно исправить, не исправив ничего из того что я написал выше. Вот это уберите из xaml `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=art }"` и это из кода `Art.DataContext = table_p;`, оно все равно не работает. И напишите вот так `Art.ItemsSource = table_p.AsDataView();`.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил. Теперь надеюсь правильно. Только вот не срабатывает Art.SelectedIndex. В combobox отображается значение первой строки, а должен быть пуст.

Comment: `Art.Text = ""` тоже не помогает?

Comment: Вам не нужно изменять код в вопросе. Если вы захотите опубликовать финальный рабочий код, вы можете сделать это в ответе.

Comment: И ```Art.Text = "``` не помогает...

Comment: А если так `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => Art.SelectedIndex = -1);` или тоже самое с текстом попробовать. Я к тому, что надо сначала комбобоксу позволить загрузить в себя данные, а уже потом манипулировать выбранным элементом.

Comment: ```Art.DisplayMemberPath = "art";
            Art.ItemsSource = table_p.AsDataView();
            Art.SelectedIndex = -1;``` Спасибо за замечание о порядке. Работает! Просто у меня был не правельный порядок строк.